# MQTT SSL peer did not return a certificate

Tags: javascript, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I generated CA, server and client certificates following the link, https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html

Also added the following lines to the mosquitto server config file.

```
listener 8883
cafile certs/ca.crt
certfile certs/server.crt
keyfile certs/server.key
require_certificate true
```

Then I wrote the below javascript client to connect to the server.

```
    var mqtt = require('mqtt');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var KEY = fs.readFileSync('G:/Projects/test/client.key');
    var CERT = fs.readFileSync('G:/Projects/test/client.crt');
    var TRUSTED_CA_LIST = [fs.readFileSync('C:/Program Files (x86)/mosquitto - Copy/certs/ca.crt')];

    var PORT = 8883;
    var HOST = 'localhost';

    var options = {
      port: PORT,
      host: HOST,
      protocol: 'mqtts',
      keyPath: KEY,
      certPath: CERT,
      passphrase: 'testnode',
      rejectUnauthorized : false,
      //The CA list will be used to determine if server is authorized
      ca: TRUSTED_CA_LIST,
      secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
      protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
      protocolVersion: 3
    };

    var client = mqtt.connect(options);

    client.subscribe('messages');
    client.publish('messages', 'Current time is: ' + new Date());
    client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
      console.log(message);
    });

    client.on('connect', function(){
        console.log('Connected');
    });
```

But when I run this code, the below error is thrown at the server.

```
1464240743: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 8883.
1464240743: OpenSSL Error: error:140890C7:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_certifica
te:peer did not return a certificate
1464240743: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a fix for this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score -2):

According to [this](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/master/examples/tls%20client/mqttclient.js).

Change `keyPath` to `key`, and `certPath`to `cert`.

Comment: Can you please add a little bit more detail to your answer (e.g. include a fixed snippet of code from the original question in the answer) to make it clearer. As it is your answer is only just slightly better than just a link. Thanks